# Length of Longest Subarray with all same elements

Tags: algorithm

I have this problem:

> You are given an array of integers *A* and an integer *k*.
> You can decrement elements of *A* up to *k* times, with the goal of producing a consecutive subarray whose elements are all equal. Return the length of the longest possible consecutive subarray that you can produce in this way.
>
> For example, if *A* is [1,7,3,4,6,5] and *k* is 6, then you can produce [1,7,3,4-1,6-1-1-1,5-1-1] = [1,7,3,3,3,3], so you will return 4.

What is the optimal solution?

Comment: Can you explain the example? why 4?

Comment: [3 4 6 5]  subarray  [3,3+1,3+3,3+2] cost of reducing is 6 to make all element equal

Comment: What is the maximum length of the original array?

Comment: N is length of original array And K is Cost

Comment: Yes I know, but I mean what is the maximum value of N?

Comment: What is your brute force approach?

Comment: maximum length is not mention in question

Comment: wait , what is the input here ?

Comment: N K A is input here

Comment: My approach Subtracting each element and store in a dictionary  then longest subarray sum

Comment: "with all same elements" this doesnt make any sense to me

Comment: it make sense take subarray [3,4,6,5]

Comment: @go_k Not sure if I got your brute force approach. You should explain it better. Either add the code or algorithm for it. If possible, mention time complexity of your brute force as well so that we can try to optimize it.

Comment: And you tagged it dynamic-programming. Are you sure dynamic prog is the way to go? If the problem is from some site, post the link so that people can try it out.

Comment: perhaps find the mean then try getting as many values as you can close to that mean? question is worded strangely, not enough toy examples. makes this annoying to try and decipher in the first place.

Comment: It can be solved in O(N*lgN) time complexity, if you are interested I can right a c++ code for it or just explain the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subarray must be made equal to its lowest member since the only allowed operation is reduction (and reducing the lowest member would add unnecessary cost). Given:

```
a1, a2, a3...an
```

the cost to reduce is:

```
sum(a1..an) - n * min(a1..an)
```

For example,

```
3, 4, 6, 5
sum = 18
min = 3
cost = 18 - 4 * 3 = 6
```

One way to reduce the complexity from `O(n^2)` to a log factor is: for each element as the rightmost (or leftmost) element of the candidate best subarray, binary search the longest length within cost. To do that, we only need the sum, which we can get from a prefix sum in O(1), the length (which we are searching on already), and minimum range query, which is well-studied.

In response to comments below this post, here is a demonstration that the sequence of costs as we extend a subarray from each element as rightmost increases monotonically and can therefore be queried with binary search.

JavaScript code:

```js
function cost(A, i, j){
  const n = j - i + 1;
  let sum = 0;
  let min = Infinity;
  for (let k=i; k<=j; k++){
    sum += A[k];
    min = Math.min(min, A[k]);
  }
  return sum - n * min;
}

function f(A){
  for (let j=0; j<A.length; j++){
    const rightmost = A[j];
    const sequence = [];
    
    for (let i=j; i>=0; i--)
      sequence.push(cost(A, i, j));
    
    console.log(rightmost + ': ' + sequence);
  }
}

var A = [1,7,3,1,4,6,5,100,1,4,6,5,3];

f(A);
```

Comment: I doubt the binary search may not work in some cases or I haven't understood your idea properly. I am interested to see how to bring the complexity below O(n^2). Can you write the C++ code for this so that I could try some inputs on it?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I haven't fully understood the idea so can't jump to the counterexample. Not a counter example though can you please edit your post to simulate for [1,7,3,1,4,6,5,100,1,4,6,5,3] k = 20. That would help me understand the optimization.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I added a section to my answer as a response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted! Now I get the whole idea. For every range, we get the `min` using the range minimum query. Using that `min` we compute the max length the possible within given cost. Additionally, we need to have the prefix sum array for `sum(a1..an)` part. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni good point - yes, we can use a prefix sum to get the sum component in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

```
def cost(a, i, j):
  n = j - i 
  s = 0
  m = a[i]
  for k in range(i,j):
    s += a[k]
    m = min(m, a[k])
  return s - n * m;

def solve(n,k,a):
 m=1
 for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i,n+1):
   if cost(a,i,j)<=k:
    x = j - i 
    if x>m:
     m=x
 return m
```

This is my python3 solution as per your specifications.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for how this code works?